# Google map (GMSMapView) calls didTapMarker delegate's method after a delay

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, geolocation, gmsmapview

It take a second before didTapMarker is called. Same with didTapAtCoordinate method.

I have a project that contains only google map and two pins in it. I try to run it on iOS9 and iOS10, same results. When I add a button it works properly.

Looks like it's trouble with a map. How to fix that?

Comment: add some code of map implementation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How big is the delay?
I've seen several cases where a small delay was caused by the device waiting to check if it is a single tap (didTapSomething) or double tap to zoom.

As stated by [Nazir](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1531661/nazir), Can we get some code?

Comment: Delay is something near 0.7 second. Issue can be solved by disabling zoom gesture in the map settings. So looks like you right. But is there any ways to disable only double tap not pinch gesture?

Comment: I don't think this is possible but you can always add in a corner of your map two button (`+` and `-`) to allow zooming by tapping those.